# java-Buble sort con array random, me aparecen numeros 0

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, random, quicksort

Estoy tratando de hacer un bubble sort con un array de numeros random sin tener mucha idea esto es lo que he conseguido hacer pero por algun motivo los numeros me aparecen como 0, por lo tanto no logro ver si se ordena que fallo podría estar haciendo?

```
public class Main {
    static Random numerosRandom = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] elementos = new int[5];
        getRandom(elementos);
        bubbleSort(elementos);
        printArray(elementos);


    }
    public static int getRandom(int[] elementos) {
        int  elementosRandom = new Random().nextInt(elementos.length);
        return elementos[elementosRandom];
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(int elementos[]){ 
        int n = elementos.length; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
                if (elementos[j] > elementos[j+1]) 
                { 
                    // swap arr[j+1] and arr[i] 
                    int temp = elementos[j]; 
                    elementos[j] = elementos[j+1]; 
                    elementos[j+1] = temp; 
                } 

    }

    public static void printArray(int [] elementos){ 

        for (int i= 0; i<elementos.length; ++i) 
            System.out.print(elementos[i] + " "); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Mmmm y si necesitara hacer un array muy grande por ejemplo 300 o 600  números debo declararlos tambien? O habría algún modo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en primera instancia decir que:

```
//Esta línea nunca la estas usando, por lo tanto deberia borrarse
static Random numerosRandom = new Random();
```

Tambien:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] elementos = new int[5];
        /*Usas el metodo getRandom, pero realmente nunca asignas nada
          a la variable elementos, (mas adelante lo explico porque). por lo tanto
          debido a que no se esta cambiando los valores del array las otras lineas
          tampoco tendrian sentido.
        */ 
        getRandom(elementos);
        bubbleSort(elementos);
        printArray(elementos);

}
```

Siguiente error:

```
//Estas regresando un solo valor, no un arreglo de ints.
public static int getRandom(int[] elementos) {

    //Obtienes un nuevo numero aleatorio, hasta ahí todo bien.
    int  elementosRandom = new Random().nextInt(elementos.length);
    /*
     Regresas lo que tenga el arreglo elementos en su pocisión elementosRandom
     pero... ¿No necesitas mas de un valor?, debes regresar es un int[] no un int
    */
    return elementos[elementosRandom];
}
```

**Siguiente cosa a tener en cuenta MUY IMPORTANTE:**

```
public static void bubbleSort(int elementos[]){ 
    int n = elementos.length; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
            if (elementos[j] > elementos[j+1]) 
            { 
                // swap arr[j+1] and arr[i] 
                int temp = elementos[j]; 
                elementos[j] = elementos[j+1]; 
                elementos[j+1] = temp; 
            } 

}
```

Esta función funciona perfectamente tál cuál la hiciste, sin embargo tiene un percance principal, y es cuando tratas de hacer la asignación al arreglo elementos:

```
/*
Debido a que te encuentras dentro de un metodo, la variable elementos es pasada como una copia de la original, es decir, tu cuando haces estas asignaciones estas cambiando es el valor de la copia, no del elemento original. 
para poder cambiar el elemento original deberas retornar algo, en este caso, un arreglo de ints y asignarselo a tu variable desde donde se encuentre
*/

elementos[j] = elementos[j+1]; 
elementos[j+1] = temp;
```

Entonces en vez de hacer esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] elementos = new int[5];
    getRandom(elementos);
    bubbleSort(elementos);
    printArray(elementos);


}

...

public static void bubbleSort(int elementos[]){ 
    int n = elementos.length; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
            if (elementos[j] > elementos[j+1]) 
            { 
                // swap arr[j+1] and arr[i] 
                int temp = elementos[j]; 
                elementos[j] = elementos[j+1]; 
                elementos[j+1] = temp; 
            } 

}
```

tendrías que haber hecho algo como esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] elementos = new int[5];
    //Suponiendo que corregiste ya esta parte tambien debes hacer una asignación
    int[] elementosRandom = getRandom(elementos);
    //Aquí se hace la asignación
    int[] elementosOrdenados = bubbleSort(elementosRandom);
    printArray(elementosOrdenados);


}

public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] elementos){ 

    int n = elementos.length;
    int[] elementosArray = elementos;

    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
            if (elementosArray[j] > elementosArray[j+1]) 
            { 
                // swap arr[j+1] and arr[i] 
                int temp = elementosArray[j+1]; 
                elementosArray[j] = elementosArray[j+1]; 
                elementosArray[j+1] = temp; 
            }

    return elementosArray;

}
```

Bien, ahora habiendo explicado estas cosas me dices que como podrias hacer en caso de que necesitaras un arreglo muy grande y como harias la asignación?, realmente la asignación no varia mucho para un arreglo normal si tu no te sabes su longitud (cuantos elementos va a contener), ya otro gallo cantaria, pero realmente podrias hacer una asignación por ciclos, tal como esto, supongamos que quieres rellenar un arreglo de ints con 600 elementos, y que cada uno de sus elementos sea aleatorio, como sabemos que son 600 elementos entonces podemos hacer algo como esto:

```
int[] miArregloGigante = new int[600];

for(int i = 0; i < miArregloGigante.length; i++){

     miArregloGigante[i] = new Random().nextInt(miArregloGigante.length);

}
```

Con algo tan sencillo como eso ya tienes un arreglo de 600 elementos rellenados con numeros totalmente aleatorios que van desde el numero 0 hasta el 599 (ya que nextInt solo toma todos los valores excepto el ultimo).

Sin embargo, yo quice hacer una pequeña versión mejorada de tu código, en la cuál se hace uso del objeto ArrayList del paquete java.util, este objeto llamado ArrayList es como la evolución de un arreglo normal de java, su sintaxis es muy diferente para declararse y sus metodos son diferentes, pero.

Su proposito general es ser usado cuando no se sabe la cantidad exacta de elementos que va a contener un array, esto debido al hecho de que el objeto ArrayList tiene la propiedad de ser estirable, es decir, tu no le tienes que decir cuantos elementos va a tener el ArrayList, tu solo preocupate por iniciarlo, eso si:

**INCISO IMPORTANTE:** Aunque el objeto ArrayList parece tener mucha ventajas respecto a un arreglo normal, ya que este es un arreglo dinamico y no estatico, debes recordar que consume mas memoria y recursos que usar un arreglo primitivo normal, por ende deberias evitar usarlo y no abusar de el, úsalo solo en casos donde especialmente no sepas que cantidad de elementos u objetos vayas a tener dentro de un arreglo.

Dicho esto, te presento tu código pero en versión ArrayList y corregido para que funcione correctamente:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> elementos = getRandom(5);
        int[] sortedArray = bubbleSort(elementos);
        printArray(sortedArray);


    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> getRandom(int quantity) {

        ArrayList<Integer> numerosRandom = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++){
            numerosRandom.add(new Random().nextInt(quantity));
        }

        return numerosRandom;
    }

    public static int[] arrayListToIntegerArray(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList){

        int i = 0;
        int[] array = new int[arrayList.size()];
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = arrayList.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){

            int element = iterator.next().intValue();
            array[i] = element;
            i++;

        }

        return array;

    }

    public static int[] bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> elementos){ 

        int n = elementos.size();
        int[] elementosArray = arrayListToIntegerArray(elementos);

        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
                if (elementosArray[j] > elementosArray[j+1]) 
                { 
                    // swap arr[j+1] and arr[i] 
                    int temp = elementosArray[j+1]; 
                    elementosArray[j] = elementosArray[j+1]; 
                    elementosArray[j+1] = temp; 
                }

        return elementosArray;

    }

    public static void printArray(int[] elementos){ 

        for (int i= 0; i<elementos.length; ++i) 
            System.out.print(elementos[i] + " "); 
    } 
}
```

Como son tan pocos los elementos que usas en el array trata de ejecutarlo varias vecez para que te arroje diferentes resultados, porque puede dar la casualidad de que varios de los valores sean iguales debido a las pocas opciones del random, pero lo probe y funciona correctamente.

Tambien si lo deseas, puedes modificar el código para hacer una versión que use menos memoria y recursos sin necesidad de usar un ArrayList, ya que como se sabe la cantidad de datos entonces no necesitas un ArrayList, sin embargo igual ahí te deje mas o menos la forma de como lo harías usando un ArrayList, solo para contemplar esa posibilidad y aprender de ello.

Comment: Hola!! muchiimas gracias por tu ayuda!! estaba mareadisima he optado por usar el array convencional porque en el ejercicio me pide el array normal, de todas formas es super genial saber como hacerlo con el array list